# How to solve a cross domain issue for fetching json data from a different url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to fetch JSON data from an URL but it's giving me an error(Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://core.agricx.com/api/Apiagricx/get_config_test. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

backend code(node js)

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Front end code(dashboard.js)

```
fetch('https://core.agricx.com/api/Apiagricx/get_config_test', {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include",
    cache: "no-cache"
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(out => {
   console.log("for out");
   console.log(out);
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log("for err");
   console.error(err);
});
```

I expected the JSON data output which you can see on directly typing the URL. But the code is going to the catch block and blocking the response I am getting from that URL.

Comment: Please make sure that this backend middleware is positioned before the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use the node.js package [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

Install the package, [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors), and include the following code at the start of your `server.js` or whatever your node code is.

```
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

Refer to the [related npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) for more details and configuring options.

Comment: I did that also but it`s not working, I am trying to fetch the data from front end js so I tried to install cors from npm and then tried app.use(cors()) but still it was not working

Comment: okay @swetasharma, are you getting any error on using it? Just add whatever you have tried to the question itself. So we'd know what else to think of.

Comment: The relevant headers aren't present on your response: if you examine the response from http://core.agricx.com/api/Apiagricx/get_config_test you won't see them. Have you deployed your code?

Comment: @Rai i have tried something like this in my server.js
let cors = require('cors'); 
app.use(cors());
but it dint work

Comment: have you installed the package `cors`? like `npm install cors` from the command line?

Comment: @Rai yes I have installed the cors package through npm.